# for loop in bash exiting to early without errors

Tags: bash

Why doesn't my for loop: for ((i=1 ;i<=$n, i++)) work? I can not figure this out. when n is for example 4, the line `echo $n` returns 4 but it does not go into the loop again. I don't get any errors either. I tried to make a small loop like:

```
for ((i=1, i<=$n; i++)); do 
    echo "this works" 
done
```

This works fine which makes it even stranger to me :/. Thanks in advance

```
read n
length=16
p=()
p[1]=50
rest=63
function s() {
    arr=($@)
    line="_____________________________________________________________________"
    for i in ${arr[@]}; do
        line=$( echo $line |  sed s/./1/$i)
    done
    echo $line
}
for ((i=1; i<=$n; i++)); do
    echo $n
    for ((j=1; j<=$length; j++)); do
        s ${p[@]}
    done
    len=${#p[@]}
    ((len=$len*2))
    for ((k=1; k<=$len; k+=2)); do
        ((p[$k+1]=p[$k]+1))
        ((p[$k]=p[$k]-1))
    done
    for ((l=1; l<=$length; l++)); do
        s ${p[@]}
        len=${#p[@]}
        for ((m=1; m<=$len; m+=2)); do
            ((p[$m+1]=p[$m+1]+1))
            ((p[$m]=p[$m]-1))
        done
    done
    ((rest=$rest-2*$length))
    ((length=$length/2))
done
```

Comment: Notice that you aren't declaring `i` local? That means it's shared between the function and the outer loop.

Comment: You've got a ton of quoting bugs in here, too. Run your code through https://shellcheck.net/, and fix what it reports.

Comment: (and get the `sed` out of here. Do your string manipulation in native bash -- using external tools to process a single line rather than a stream is horrible for efficiency).

Comment: Also, the `function` keyword gives you no advantage over the POSIX-compliant `foo() {` function declaration syntax. Consider omitting it -- there are a great many places where bashisms add value, but that particular one has no benefits to compensate for the loss of compatibility across shells.

Comment: Thank you, for spellcheck, seems great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't declare your variables local, they're global -- so the loop in your `s` function is overwriting the same `i` counter used outside the function, leading to the outer loop's early exit.

Consider using the below code:

```
s() {
    local -a arr  # declare a function-local array (sparse, like all bash arrays)
    local i       # ...and a function-local counter

    for i; do     # by default, a for statement iterates over "$@"; that works for us.
      arr[$i]=1   # specifically set a value only for named items
    done

    # ...thereafter, iterate through the range of characters we want to print...
    for ((i=0; i<70; i++)); do
      printf '%s' "${arr[$i]:-_}" # and print the array entry if present, or an _ otherwise
    done
    printf '\n'                   # ...followed by a trailing newline.
}
```